# Light points effect 2D

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm a new developer for WP7, so my knowledge is basic. I would develop an app where I have a map 2D (simply an image) where randomly light points appear in this "background" in several points of background.

Can you explain me how I can generate these points and a code example (C#) ?

Comment: what do you mean by light points?

Comment: Light points like "Dragon ball Radar" :-)
http://shenronsaint.free.fr/objets/radar.jpg
This is my purpose